# How do I prove that $a^{\log_a(b)}=b$?

Tags: exponential-function

All in the title basically. Not sure how to prove $a^{\log_a(b)}=b$.

Don't know how to use the rules to get that.

Comment: That's the standard definition of $\log_a b$.  If you want to use a different definition, you should specify which.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $x^{\log_x n}=n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/why-is-x-log-x-n-n)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of logarithm will do

You may also use the following argument

Let $a^x=b$ and solve for $x$

Take logarithm and you get $\log a^x=\log b$

$$x \log a =\log b$$

$$x=\frac {\log b}{\log a} =\log _a b$$